# Fluent NHibernate mapping throws an exception of 'Id is not mapped'

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I need help with auto mapping in Fluent Nhibernate. Here's the tables I want to have in my app (they are many of them, but I want to start from mapping only a few of them)

Well, I'd like to use the `AutoMapping` functionality because I don't want to write the mapping classes for more than 100 tables...

Anyway, here's the error thrown when creating the `SessionFactory` (the code is at the end of this post)

> The entity 'FilterConfig' doesn't have an Id mapped.
>   Use the Id method to map your identity property. For example: Id(x => x.Id).

[image]

Entities (**I hope I created them correctly**):

```
public partial class UserLogin
{
    public UserLogin()
    {
        this.UserMessages = new List<UserMessage>();
        this.UserMessagesReceivers = new List<UserMessagesReceiver>();
    }

    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual int UserTypeID { get; set; }
    public virtual int? StudentID { get; set; }
    public virtual int? HeadmasterID { get; set; }
    public virtual int? ParentID { get; set; }
    public virtual string UniqueID { get; set; }
    public virtual bool ShowMyPhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsBanned { get; set; }
    public virtual string Login { get; set; }
    public virtual string Password { get; set; }
    public virtual bool WasPasswordSent { get; set; }
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual string UserPicture { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<UserMessage> UserMessages { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<UserMessagesReceiver> UserMessagesReceivers { get; set; }
}

public partial class UserMessage
{
    public UserMessage()
    {
        this.UserMessagesReceivers = new List<UserMessagesReceiver>();
        this.UserMessagesReplies = new List<UserMessagesReply>();
    }

    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? LastCheckDate { get; set; }
    public virtual int UserLoginID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual bool HasNonCheckedReplies { get; set; }
    public virtual UserLogin UserLogin { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<UserMessagesReceiver> UserMessagesReceivers { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<UserMessagesReply> UserMessagesReplies { get; set; }
}

public partial class UserMessagesReceiver
{
    public UserMessagesReceiver()
    {
        this.WasMessageChecked = false;
        this.UserMessagesReplies = new List<UserMessagesReply>();
    }

    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual int UserMessagesID { get; set; }
    public virtual int ReceiverLoginID { get; set; }
    public virtual bool WasMessageChecked { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? LastCheckedDate { get; set; }
    public virtual UserLogin UserLogin { get; set; }
    public virtual UserMessage UserMessage { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<UserMessagesReply> UserMessagesReplies { get; set; }
}

public partial class UserMessagesReply
{
    public UserMessagesReply()
    {
    }

    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public virtual int UserMessagesID { get; set; }
    public virtual int? UserMessagesReceiverID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual UserMessage UserMessage { get; set; }
    public virtual UserMessagesReceiver UserMessagesReceiver { get; set; }
}
```

Configuration:

```
    public class AutomappingConfiguration : DefaultAutomappingConfiguration
    {
        public override bool IsId(Member member)
        {
            return member.Name == member.DeclaringType.Name + "ID";
        }
    }

    private static AutoPersistenceModel CreateAutomappings()
    {
        return AutoMap.AssemblyOf<AutomappingConfiguration>(new AutomappingConfiguration());
    }

    private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
    {
        var cfg = new AutomappingConfiguration();
        return Fluently.Configure()
                       .Database(MySQLConfiguration.Standard
                       .ConnectionString("..."))
                       .Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings
                                       .Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<UserLogin>(cfg))
                                       .Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<UserMessage>(cfg))
                                       .Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<UserMessagesReceiver>(cfg))
                                       .Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<UserMessagesReply>(cfg)))
                       .BuildSessionFactory();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

in the configuration you said that the Ids are named like `UserLoginID` but in the class they are defined as `public virtual int ID { get; set; }` so change

```
return member.Name == member.DeclaringType.Name + "ID";
```

to

```
return member.Name == "ID";
```

Some additional info:

- CreateAutomappings() seems to be not used
- AutomappingConfiguration should at least override ShouldMap(Member) to filter on the namespace (e.g. `member.Namespace.StartsWith(typeof(UserMessage).Namespace)`) otherwise sooner or later utility classes and the like will be mapped as well
- AutoMap.AssemblyOf<> should be called per assembly containing types not per type